# como ordenar en mysql con un contador

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, contador

Quisiera saber como puedo ordenar una data con un contador en mysql tengo una data ordenada por nivel y alfabéticamente pero en la columna position los números no son correlativos y necesito también ordenarlos por position respetando los niveles y el orden alfabético por ejemplo... nivel 1 position 1 value AA, nivel 1 position 2 value AB, nivel 1 position 3 value AC, nivel 2 position 1 value AA, nivel 2 position 2 value AB, nivel 2 position 3 value AC... es posible hacer eso ?... es decir hacerle un update a la columna position para que coloque los números correlativos respetando los niveles y el orden alfabético

[image: data a ordenar]

Comment: Nos compartes que has intentado?

Comment: la verdad despues de obtener esto no he intentado nada porque no tengo idea de como colocar un contador en un query

Comment: Cualquier intento o avance ayuda

Comment: lo unico que hice fue aislar la data con este query 

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `usa_catalog_category_entity_brand_layoffpain2`
SELECT DISTINCT a.entity_id,
a.attribute_set_id,
a.parent_id,
a.created_at,
a.updated_at,
a.path,
a.position,
a.level,
a.children_count,
b.value
FROM`usa_catalog_category_entity` a
INNER JOIN `usa_catalog_category_entity_varchar` b
ON a.entity_id=b.entity_id 
WHERE attribute_id='41'
ORDER BY parent_id,VALUE,LEVEL,entity_id;

para ordenarlo alfabéticamente y por nivel

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que necesitas es algo como `ORDER BY level, position, value` haciendo eso ordenará primero por nivel, luego por posición y luego por value.

Comment: no, no me explique bien si se fija en la imagen esta ordenado alfabeticamente y ese es el orden que quiero mantener quiero es cambiar la numeracion de la columna position para que sea correlativo sin alterar el orden de la columna value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un update con una subconsulta puede lograr lo que necesitas. Por ejemplo puedes hacer:

```
update t, (
  select
    level, 
    value,
    row_number() over(partition by level order by value) as rn
  from t
) as x
set t.position = x.rn
where t.level = x.level and t.value = x.value
```

Resultado:

```
 position  level  value 
 --------- ------ ----- 
        1      1  AA    
        2      1  AB    
        3      1  AC    
        1      2  AA    
        2      2  AB    
        3      2  AC
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8K5VuTmkAEjut8M9ZCrTed/0).